# How to set the connection of associated table in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I actually have 2 databases, one named as `clientDefaultDb` and `client1Db`.
here's the code of association.

**ProductsController**

```
    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('client1Db');
    $productSource = TableRegistry::get('Products', ['connection' => 
             $connection]);

    $products = $productSource->find('all');
    $products->contain(['ProductUnits']);
```

Here we set the connection of the table to `Client1Db`
and I call the `contain` with `ProductUnits`

**ProductTable.php**

```
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('products');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('ProductUnits')
            ->setForeignKey([
                'item_code'
            ])
            ->setBindingKey([
                'item_code'
            ]);

    }
```

The return is no error.
It fetched the product correctly and have some data, but the problem is there's no data at ProductUnits it's empty.

I tried to manually query directly to the database it return something.
Tried copying the data of `ProductUnits` at `Client1Db` then pasted it to the `clientDefaultDb` then I tried running the code again, and the `ProductUnits` return the data that i've been copied.
so probably all associated table is difinetely connected to  the default database.
So how can I change the default connection of the associated tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work. Thanks @burzum for the idea.

here's the code.

```
$this->loadModel('ProductUnits'); 
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('client1Db'); 
$this->ProductUnits->setConnection($connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Table::setConnection()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_setConnection) on the associated models.

```
$this->SomeAssoc->setConnection(/* connection here */);
```

Comment: Its not working it throws `Undefined property: ProductsController::$ProductUnits in /var/www/html/api-server/src/Controller/Api/ProductsController.php`